# How Do I Add Image To Tkinter Treeview Other Than First Column

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm new to learning the Treeview widget and have been trying to find information about how to add my own custom icon.png to columns instead of just text data. I'm only able to insert images to the first column, but haven't seen any options for adding them to additional columns (2nd column, 3rd column, etc., etc..)

Here's what I'm currently using:

```
green_dot = PhotoImage(file='imgs/green-dot.png')

#Insert/Add row:
tv.insert(parent='', index=0, iid=0, image=green_dot, text='', tag='green', values=('1', 'Aaron Catono', 'AaronCatono1@gmail.com'))
```